# Step by step instruction for secure replication?

Tags: oauth, couchdb, replication

Not sure if the question should rather be on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[couchdb]+replication)?

I have a couchDB setup on my server using [Apache credentials](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-948KKJ) (but I can switch that off if it is an distraction).
I have local instances on various laptops. Now I want to setup secure (continuous) replication. From my understanding I could use username/password, SSL certificates or OAuth. I found bits and pieces of information:

- [SSL Question on serverFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/456320/how-to-configure-ssl-for-couchdb)
- [the WIKI entry on replication](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#New_features_introduced_in_CouchDB_1.2.0)
- [how to on replication](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_replicate_a_database) in the wiki
- [the gist on 1.2 replication](https://gist.github.com/832610)
- [the replication algorythm](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/wiki/Replication-Algorithm)

All this documents added a hunch, but also confusion (I'm just a [simple mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh)).

What I'm looking for is a step by step instruction:

- Pro and con for OAuth or SSL certificates (optional discussion)
- Steps to setup the SSL components **Clarification**: I'm not looking for SSL transport security - that's not really complicated and documented well for both [Apache HTTP](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html) and CouchDB. What I'm looking for is **authentication using certificates**, similar to what you can do in SSH. The potential problem I see with OAuth: a admin has full access to the credentials (?). With a certificate approach (s)he can't impersonate the user since the private key is not under admin control.
- Steps to setup OAuth
- Sample replication documents for the each user uses a local replica with some documents and share one oneline

Where could I find that?

Comment: **Clarification**: I'm not looking for SSL transport security - that's not really complicated and documented well for both [Apache HTTP](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html) and CouchDB. What I'm looking for is **authentication using certificates**, similar to what you can do in SSH. The potential problem I see with OAuth: a admin has full access to the credentials (?). With a certificate approach (s)he can't impersonate the user since the private key is not under admin control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secure transfer of user credentials is a very delicate question.

If we wouldn't look on third-party, in most cases, SSL is better way to start from since it has wide support by every tool you might used. SSL certificate, provides not only encryption (even self-signed ones), but insurance that user had requested right resource. Last option also worth to be highlighted if you're care about server security. The main drawback of SSL usage is performance degradation (vary on used algorithm) since server have to decrypt data and client need to validate certificate in additional to common communication routines. Also you have to pay some money for trusted certificate ([not always true](https://www.startssl.com/?app=40)).

Using OAuth allows to not disclose real user credentials and easily maintain their access control from server side. Also, you need some library that handle OAuth 1.0 specification properly and if your platform miss such - you have to implement it by your own. In additional OAuth provides transfer data signing, so it aims to be safe for MiTM case. That's actually all that he does.

As you note, SSL and OAuth are about two different things: SSL helps to encrypt data on transport level (TLS) while OAuth take care about credentials disclosure in non secure environment. They are not replacement for each other, but each of them may stand as good additional to other.

To setup SSL support for CouchDB just follow the [documentation guide](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ssl.html). It's quite simple and easy to do. Note, that if there is some proxy server in front of CouchDB, it might be wise to setup SSL for him and proxy data to local CouchDB instance via regular HTTP protocol.

To setup OAuth there need to make next steps:
0. Ensure that `{couch_httpd_oauth, oauth_authentication_handler}` handler is exists for `authentication_handlers` option of `[httpd]` section for `default.ini` config file:

[httpd]
  authentication_handlers = {couch_httpd_oauth, oauth_authentication_handler}, {couch_httpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}

After that you need to edit your `local.ini` file in next way:

1. Setup consumer secret:

```
[oauth_consumer_secrets] 
example.org = sekr1t
```

1. Setup token secrets:

```
[oauth_token_secrets] 
token1 = tokensekr1t
```

1. Map tokens to existed CouchDB user:

```
[oauth_token_users] 
token1 = joe
```

That's all! If you have CouchDB version 1.2 or higher, you may also define OAuth credentials within user document inside `_users` database:

```
{
    "_id": "org.couchdb.user:joe",
    "type": "user",
    "name": "joe",
    "password_sha": "fe95df1ca59a9b567bdca5cbaf8412abd6e06121",
    "salt": "4e170ffeb6f34daecfd814dfb4001a73"
    "roles": ["foo", "bar"],
    "oauth": {
        "consumer_keys": {
            "example.org": "sekr1t",
            "consumerKey2": "key2Secret"
        },
        "tokens": {
            "token1": "tokensekr1t",
            "token2": "token2Secret"
       }
    }
}
```

Now, when we'd setup OAuth credentials for our user *joe*, let's start our replication. To let CouchDB use OAuth credentials, we need to extend `source` or `target` fields, depending on which side will authorize our user:

```
{
    "source": "mailbox",
    "target": {
        "url": "https://secure.example.org/mailbox",
        "auth": {
            "oauth": {
                "consumer_secret": "sekr1t", 
                "consumer_key": "example.org", 
                "token_secret": "tokensekr1t", 
                "token": "token1" 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

and `POST` this data to `_replicate` resource or create document for `_replicator` database. Replication will start from local server to remote `secure.example.org` using SSL protocol encryption and all operations will goes for remote user with login `joe`.

Summarizing: combination of SSL and OAuth allows you not only protect transfered data (not only user credentials) and insure that target server was not faked, but also protects real user login name and password from accidental disclosure, control consumer sources (e.g. if `example.org` will be compromised, we can only remove his consumer token, but not force user to change his password) and signing requests for additional protection against MiTM attacks.

**UPDATE**: For your case regular SSL certificate routines are ok: you will need to create personal certificates signed by your own and let clients to setup for further work with your CouchDB. The only thing required from CouchDB side is to validate certificates before process the connection. But note, that custom personal SSL certificate installation may be [not trivial](http://tig.csail.mit.edu/wiki/TIG/IPhoneCertsInstall) especially for mobile clients.

Speaking for OAuth side, CouchDB *may* use RSA-SHA1 auth method that uses some kind of personal certificate for secret. However, you need to patch sources first to unlock this method - it's disabled by default.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. And sorry for not being clear. I'm not confused by SSL for transport security (I know how to do that) but SSL certificates for authentication (an option couchDB seems to have). Probably "SSL certificate" is misleading and it should be called "X509 cert or so". The approach seems similar to SSH where you can use certificates instead of username/password

Comment: @stwissel sorry for late response! I'd made update about your clarification.

Comment: Thx for the update. SSLCerts certainly are a lot of fun! I'll ask (in due time) another question about the RSA-SHA1. Having all the tokens and secrets in theopen is Ok for now, but might not survive a secaudit

Comment: @stwissel actually, they aren't opened for all: 1) you may define them in config file that is only accessible for CouchDB or server admins or 2) in user document which is readable for CouchDB admins and user that he belongs to (1.2+). In both cases, Bob never have a chance to get Alice token/secret unless he is admin, but if he is he may do a lot of other harmful things(:

Comment: Our security auditors - rightly - flag any configuration where an Admin can impersonate a user by accessing unencrypted credentials as "not production ready". That's the whole idea of public/private keys. The public key allows you to verify that it is me, but not to pretend to be me. Unfortunately key management is a mess on almost all systems :-)