# OAuth replication with certificates?

Tags: oauth, erlang, couchdb

Thanks to a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127066/step-by-step-instruction-for-secure-replication) from @Kxepal making OAuth work with CouchDB replication works. Now I'm looking for insight how to replace the keys known to the admin with X509 (or others) keys, so the admin would only have the public key of the user and could not impersonate one.

What would be the steps to enable replication for CouchDB using keys for OAuth authentication.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [sf] or [security.se].

Comment: Actually you can do that downloading the source code and modifying "apache-couchdb-1.5.0/src/couchdb/couch_httpd_oauth.erl" for a custom implementation, the default couchdb implementation works with keys only.

Comment: Hhm. My Erlang is worse than my Mandarin, so unless I can bribe someone, that's not an option